# Button click event not fired after moving it to the asp:content

Tags: asp.net, vba

I just moved the `button` from `html` to the `asp:content` because I use `master page` :

```
<asp:content id="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"></asp:CustomValidator>
            <br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
    </div>
</asp:content>
```

The following code was working before I moved it, now the click event is not getting fired :

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

And it gave me an error (This error didn't occur before):

> Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

So I added the below line of code :

```
Private WithEvents Button1 As Button
```

> But still, the `button1` is never fired.

Please kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ContentPlaceHolder` is a different `NamingContainer` than the `Page`(it implements `INamingContainer`),  so it's not initialized automatically from ASP.NET if you declare the variable `Private WithEvents Button1 As Button`.

You have to  attach the event handler declaratively (or programmatically from codebehind):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
```

and remove the `Handles` clause, the method **must** now be at least `Protected`:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 

End Sub
```